# Yii Framework: Send mail to multiple recipients with YiiMailMessage

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I need to add multiple CC email recipients using YiiMailMessage. Recipients get them from a table.

Try these ways and does not work

```
$message->cc=("mail1@gmail.com, mail2@gmail.com");
$message->cc=("mail1@gmail.com; mail2@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an array of recipients:

`$message->cc=(array("mail1@gmail.com","mail2@gmail.com"));`